# Is there a platform that bundles HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript into a native mobile app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-phones, platform

Is there a platform I can use that takes all the technologies mentioned in the title and packages a native application for the most popular mobile Operating Systems (Android, iOS, RIM, WP7 etc)?

Thank you.

Comment: That's what I was asking, perfect. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, yes - PhoneGap and Titanium Appcelerator are particularly suitable for this.

Someone I follow on Twitter did a nice write of comparing Appcelerator VS. PhoneGap VS. Adobe Air:
http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/appcelerator-vs-phonegap-vs-adobe-air

I've only used PhoneGap and dabbled briefly with Appcelerator. I found that PhoneGap *used* to be better, but that may no longer be the case it seems.

Comment: Thank you, Iain. Most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, its called PhoneGap. [PhoneGap Home](http://www.phonegap.com/)

The first option requires you to build a file in an IDE. The second option they have is to upload a zip file in a certain format and they do the IDE work: [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)

I have used both. They are quite fun to use! Read the APIs, the application is a little different in build structure than a typical web application.

Comment: PhoneGap cannot be used to create a native application afaik.

Comment: It can, to an extent. I have built many little apps. It essentially is a wrapper for some of the code, but it ties into the APIs and allows integration with the GPS, accelerometor, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a software like Appcelerator Titanium to build applications for multiple platforms.

You can learn more at http://www.appcelerator.com

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to use any of the native libraries each of the platform provides, you're better off providing a mobile web site and instructing your users to bookmark it (you can bookmark pages to the homescreen in most of those platforms). Much less intrusive, much more simpler and maintainable.

Comment: Amen. This native platform that bundles HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript is called a web browser.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I want it to be an application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and check out http://jquerymobile.com/